# How can I find a specific element in a List<T>?

Tags: c#, list, properties, find

My application uses a list like this:

`List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();`

Using the `Add` method, another instance of `MyClass` is added to the list.

`MyClass` provides, among others, the following methods:

```
public void SetId(String Id);
public String GetId();
```

How can I find a specific instance of `MyClass` by means of using the `GetId` method? I know there is the `Find` method, but I don't know if this would work here?!

Answer (score 342, accepted):

Use a lambda expression

```
MyClass result = list.Find(x => x.GetId() == "xy");
```

---

Note: C# has a built-in syntax for properties. Instead of writing getter and setter as ordinary methods (as you might be used to from Java), write

```
private string _id;
public string Id
{
    get
    {
        return _id;
    }
    set
    {
        _id = value;
    }
}
```

`value` is an implicit parameter to the set accessor (but this may be about to change according to this [LDM](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/2024/LDM-2024-03-04.md#breaking-changes-making-field-and-value-contextual-keywords)). It contains the value assigned to the property.

Since this pattern is often used, C# provides  [auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties). They are a short version of the code above; however, the backing variable is hidden and not accessible (it is accessible from within the class in VB, however).

```
public string Id { get; set; }
```

You can simply use properties as if you were accessing a field:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
obj.Id = "xy";       // Calls the setter with "xy" assigned to the value parameter.
string id = obj.Id;  // Calls the getter.
```

---

Using properties, you would search for items in the list like this

```
MyClass result = list.Find(x => x.Id == "xy");
```

---

You can also use auto-implemented properties if you need a read-only property:

```
public string Id { get; private set; }
```

This enables you to set the `Id` within the class but not from outside. If you need to set it in derived classes as well you can also protect the setter

```
public string Id { get; protected set; }
```

---

And finally, you can declare properties as `virtual` and override them in deriving classes, allowing you to provide different implementations for getters and setters; just as for ordinary virtual methods. In the deriving class you can override only the getter or only the setter. The other accessor is inherited without changes.

---

Since C# 6.0 (Visual Studio 2015, Roslyn) you can write getter-only auto-properties with an inline initializer

```
public string Id { get; } = "A07"; // Evaluated once when object is initialized.
```

You can also initialize getter-only properties within the constructor instead. Getter-only auto-properties are **true** read-only properties, unlike auto-implemented properties with a private setter.

This works also with read-write auto-properties:

```
public string Id { get; set; } = "A07";
```

Beginning with C# 6.0 you can also write properties as expression-bodied members

```
public DateTime Yesterday => DateTime.Date.AddDays(-1); // Evaluated at each call.
// Instead of
public DateTime Yesterday { get { return DateTime.Date.AddDays(-1); } }
```

See: [.NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn")](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)
         [The history of C# (version history)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history)

Starting with [C# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/), both, getter and setter, can be written with expression bodies:

```
public string Name
{
    get => _name;                                // getter
    set => _name = value;                        // setter
}
```

Note that in this case the setter must be an expression. It cannot be a statement. The example above works, because in C# an assignment can be used as an expression or as a statement. The value of an assignment expression is the assigned value where the assignment itself is a side effect. This allows you to assign a value to more than one variable at once: `x = y = z = 0` is equivalent to `x = (y = (z = 0))` and has the same effect as the statements `z = 0; y = 0; x = 0;`.

Since C# 9.0 you can use read-only (or better initialize-once) properties that you can initialize in an object initializer. This is currently not possible with getter-only properties.

```
public string Name { get; init; }

var c = new C { Name = "c-sharp" };
```

Beginning with C# 11, you can have a `required` property to force client code to initialize it.

The `field` keyword is planned for a future version of C# (it did not make it into C# 11 and C# 12) and allows the access to the automatically created backing field in a semi-auto-implemented property.

```
// Removes time part in setter
public DateTime HiredDate { get; init => field = value.Date(); }

public Data LazyData => field ??= new Data();
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. For db operation it would look something like this:
`IQueryable<T> result = db.Set<T>().Find(//just id here//).ToList();`
It would already know that you are looking for primary key. Just for info.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I'd separate the get and set into different methods so that the value is not accidentally set during a comparison.

Comment: @JoelTrauger: A comparison reads the property and therefore only calls the getter.

Comment: This is true, but an accidental assignment will call the setter and modify the property. See `return object.property = value` vs `return object.property == value`

Comment: An accidental call of a separate set method will modify the property as well. I don't see how separate get set methods can improve safety.

Answer (score 24):

```
var list = new List<MyClass>();
var item = list.Find( x => x.GetId() == "TARGET_ID" );
```

or if there is only one and you want to enforce that something like `SingleOrDefault` may be what you want

```
var item = list.SingleOrDefault( x => x.GetId() == "TARGET" );

if ( item == null )
    throw new Exception();
```

Comment: Why will you use singleOrDefault if you want to throw exception, Use Single()

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
 list.Find(item => item.id==myid);
```

Answer (score 7):

Or if you do not prefer to use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) you can do it the old-school way:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
foreach (MyClass element in list)
{
    if (element.GetId() == "heres_where_you_put_what_you_are_looking_for")
    {

        break; // If you only want to find the first instance a break here would be best for your application
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) extensions:

```
string id = "hello";
MyClass result = list.Where(m => m.GetId() == id).First();
```

Comment: or the other overload of First: `MyClass result = list.First(m => m.GetId() == id);
`

Answer (score 4):

You can solve your problem most concisely with a predicate written using anonymous method syntax:

```
MyClass found = list.Find(item => item.GetID() == ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<DealsCategory> DealCategory { get; set; }
int categoryid = Convert.ToInt16(dealsModel.DealCategory.Select(x => x.Id));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a search variable to hold your searching criteria. Here is an example using database.

```
 var query = from o in this.mJDBDataset.Products 
             where o.ProductStatus == textBox1.Text || o.Karrot == textBox1.Text 
             || o.ProductDetails == textBox1.Text || o.DepositDate == textBox1.Text 
             || o.SellDate == textBox1.Text
             select o;

 dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();

 //Search and Calculate
 search = textBox1.Text;
 cnn.Open();
 string query1 = string.Format("select * from Products where ProductStatus='"
               + search +"'");
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query1, cnn);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds, "Products");
 SqlDataReader reader;
 reader = new SqlCommand(query1, cnn).ExecuteReader();

 List<double> DuePayment = new List<double>();

 if (reader.HasRows)
 {

  while (reader.Read())
  {

   foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Products"].Rows)
   {

     DuePaymentstring.Add(row["DuePayment"].ToString());
     DuePayment = DuePaymentstring.Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();

   }
  }

  tdp = 0;
  tdp = DuePayment.Sum();                        
  DuePaymentstring.Remove(Convert.ToString(DuePaymentstring.Count));
  DuePayment.Clear();
 }
 cnn.Close();
 label3.Text = Convert.ToString(tdp + " Due Payment Count: " + 
 DuePayment.Count + " Due Payment string Count: " + DuePaymentstring.Count);
 tdp = 0;
 //DuePaymentstring.RemoveRange(0,DuePaymentstring.Count);
 //DuePayment.RemoveRange(0, DuePayment.Count);
 //Search and Calculate
```

Here "var query" is generating the search criteria you are giving through the search variable. Then "DuePaymentstring.Select" is selecting the data matching your given criteria. Feel free to ask if you have problem understanding.