# Find element in List<> that contains a value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a `List<MyClass> MyList` where

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Given a name, I'd like to get the corresponding value. I have it currently implemented as:

```
MyList[MyList.FindIndex(item => String.Compare(item.name, "foo", 0) == 0)].value
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How can I find a specific element in a List<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854917/how-can-i-find-a-specific-element-in-a-listt)*.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Either use LINQ:

```
var value = MyList.First(item => item.name == "foo").value;
```

(This will just find the first match, of course. There are lots of options around this.)

Or use [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) instead of `FindIndex`:

```
var value = MyList.Find(item => item.name == "foo").value;
```

I'd strongly suggest using LINQ though - it's a much more idiomatic approach these days.

(I'd also suggest following the .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: Don't forget to check for nulls before calling `.value`

Comment: @banging: I was trying to write something which had the same assumptions that the original code did - the original code would go bang if the value wasn't found, so this does too.

Comment: Ty. When you say .net naming convention, did you mean not capitalizing the starting letters of object names? ( **M**yList vs myList) or something else?

Comment: @RaGe: I was more talking about the properties. But if `MyList` isn't a property or a constant, it should probably be `myList`, yes. Not that I'm ever keen on `my` as a prefix for names.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry Jon, that note was not really for you but a general reminder for people learning ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet How do I use LINQ in visual studio against my List<> ? Only non-linq methods appear, FindIndex in this case.

Comment: @guiomie: Make sure you have a using directive for System.Linq.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `Where` to filter and `Select` to get the desired value.

```
MyList.Where(i=>i.name == yourName).Select(j=>j.value);
```

Comment: I just refreshed and Skeet's answer said "4 mins ago" while Hosseins said "3 mins ago"... and now they are both at 4. I'll call it a tie (they both didn't know the other was answering)

Comment: and all the comments on this answer are disappearing

Comment: @Cemafor: I saw that Hossein was answering, but I've given a slightly different answer - because it only finds *one* value. (That's all that's been indicated as a requirement.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm not sure if you saw, but there was a converstion in the comments about the relative timing of your and Hossein's answers.  And you are (of course) correct, your answer is more of a passive in place switch then Hossein's, whos would return all matches.

Comment: @Cemafor: I didn't see the comments - just yours. I was just trying to explain that *similar* but distinct answers are possible even with awareness of each other :)

Comment: Shouldn't the "=" be "=="?

Answer (score 7):

I would use `.Equals()` for comparison instead of `==`.

Like so:

```
MyClass item = MyList.Find(item => item.name.Equals("foo"));
```

Particularly because it gives you options like StringComparison, which is awesome. Example:

```
MyClass item = MyList.Find(item => item.name.Equals("foo", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

This enables your code to ignore special characters, upper and lower case. There are more options.

Answer (score 5):

Using function Find is cleaner way.

```
MyClass item = MyList.Find(item => item.name == "foo");
if (item != null) // check item isn't null
{
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Enumerable.First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx) returns the element instead of an index. In both cases you will get an exception if no matching element appears in the list (your original code will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to get the item at index -1, but `First` will throw an `InvalidOperationException`).

```
MyList.First(item => string.Equals("foo", item.name)).value
```

Answer (score -2):

hi body very late but i am writing

if(mylist.contains(value)){}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's unclear how this answers the question. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: I could only see the answer. Sorry, I removed it so to not confuse anyone. All I could see was the comment and didnt see any of the tags or details on the question so I had to make some assumptions. I removed it